# taken of you meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the following phrase;

```
Due cognisance is taken of you reticence regarding item 2
```

I can not understand anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a typo. The sentence should read

> Due cognisance is taken of **your** reticence regarding item 2

In this case, *your reticence regarding item 2* is the object of the preposition *of*.

The sentence means, roughly, "*We notice your reluctance to speak about item #2.*" It's phrased in the passive voice, so it is better paraphrased as, "*Your reluctance to speak about item #2 has been noticed.*"

To [*take cognizance of*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-cognizance-of) something means to acknowledge or notice it. Here, the thing being noticed is *your reticence* (or *reluctance to speak*) about item 2.

Comment: I'm not sure *reticence* here can be accurately replaced by just *reluctance*. It's quite possible "item 2" is actually something the person being addressed is very keen to see happen - the speaker may simply be noting that the other person has said very little about item 2 (his "project", that he's trying to promote), *because he's reluctant to divulge details at an early stage in negotiations*.

Comment: As @FumbleFIngers says, *reticent* does not mean *reluctant*, although it may mean *reluctant **to speak***. This use of *reticence*  has become epidemic in US business circles over the last six or eight years, and if we work at it we might be able to stamp it out before it kills a very useful word.

Comment: The edit is good, but I see no harm in leaving these comments here. There are tens of thousands of instances of [*they're reticent to {do whatever}*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22they%27re+reticent+to%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) out there on the Interweb. (Someone's gotta take a stand! :)